# How can I save a stream of Json data to a text file in C# Windows Forms app?

Tags: c#, json, winforms

I've got a stream of data incoming as a Json file and I'm trying to save it to a text file, I've got it working here below however, when i check the file, it only has the last Json message received saved, I am trying to get it so that once it saves a line it goes onto a new line and prints the latest Json message below. at the moment it will print let's say 1000 lines but they are all the same and they match the latest Json received.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
void ReceiveData() //This function is used to listen for messages from the flight simulator
{
    while (true)
    {
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream(); //sets the network stream to the client's stream
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256]; //Defines the max amount of bytes that can be sent
        int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            string jsonreceived = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead); //Converts the received data into ASCII for the json variable
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            TelemetryUpdate telemetry = serializer.Deserialize<TelemetryUpdate>(jsonreceived);
            this.Invoke(new Action(() => { TelemetryReceivedLabel.Text = jsonreceived; 
            })) ;

            Updatelabels(telemetry); //runs the update labels function with the telemetry data as an argument
                
            File.Delete(@"c:\temp\BLACKBOX.txt"); // this deletes the original file
            string path = @"c:\temp\BLACKBOX.txt"; //this stores the path of the file in a string                                  

            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path)) // Create a file to write to.
            {
                for (int i = 0; i<10000; i++)
                {
                    sw.Write(jsonreceived.ToString()); //writes the json data to the file
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're deleting the file each time you get new data, so no surprise there. Use [File.AppendAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalltext) instead (and don't delete the file :)

Answer (score 0):

As per the .NET documentation for [`File.CreateText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.createtext?view=net-7.0):

> Creates or opens a file for writing UTF-8 encoded text. **If the file already exists, its contents are overwritten.**

So, every time you call `File.CreateText` you're creating a new StreamWriter that's going to overwrite the contents of your file.  Try using [`File.AppendText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendtext?view=net-7.0) instead to pick up where you left off.